# WSO2 ESB Carbon app undeploy after deploy automatically with no log error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a carbon app that I want to deploy in wso2 esb. I deploy it and I can see in the log how is successfully deployed, but after that it starts to undeploy with any error shown. Here is the log entries:

```
TID: [0] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-07-12 15:13:46,521] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} - Successfully Undeployed Carbon Application : myApp {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
TID: [0] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-07-12 15:13:46,425] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} - Undeploying Carbon Application : myApp... {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager
TID: [0] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-07-12 15:13:23,551] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} - Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : myApp {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager
TID: [0] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-07-12 15:13:22,727] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} - Deploying Carbon Application : myApp-1.0.0.car... {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager
```

Sometimes I can even see the proxy created, but after a few seconds the app has gone from the app list.

Any help or idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy only the proxy service and see what happens.

Comment: I dont get behaviour when have no registry resources

Answer (score 0):

What do you have there in as registry resources and what is the server roles of the Registry resources?

If you want to deploy registry resource in the C-App in to ESB, you need to change the Server roles of the registry resources to ESB server role.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana